# what is most reliable css selector to select google search result?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am building an extension that enhances google search result. However, I am concerned that using selector `.g` is going to break the extension in future and I have no idea if this selector keeps changes, all of google's classes already seem machine generated to begin with.

Is `.g` Reliable. Or has it been changing. Should I look for `a` tag instead and go from there.

Comment: I don't think there is an answer for this. Google could change this at any moment and you (or I) would have no control over it

Comment: Agree with Liam, MAYBE `data-hveid` is little bit more stable (assuming HTML and CSS are minified by a tool) but even in that case they're free to change it in any moment

Comment: yes theoretically you are right there is always possibility. But realistically and statistically, if you see somethings dont change. There is always been `a` tag, and wrapped inside `h3` tag. I am wondering if this is also the case for some classes.

Answer (score 3):

Class names and ids are generally first choices when it comes to choosing how to locate an element. But, not every class value is a good thing to use inside CSS selectors or XPath expressions. For example, bootstrap classes like `col-xs-8` or `col-sm-offset-11` should not be used for this since they are *layout-* and not *data-* oriented. Class names like "product" or "searchResult" are much better fit if provided - these class names describe the underlying elements perfectly.

Back to your example. In general, a class value like `g` is far from being a good and reliable locator. It is not readable and does not provide any information about what it represents. But, we are talking about google search result page here. In this case, I would say `g` is pretty much a good location technique since there is a low probability it would change in the nearest future.

Make sure to have a good error-handling and notification mechanism implemented in your scraper, so that you would know when the change would happen and the code would break.

`#search h3 > a` is probably a bit better approach though since it can be explained easily - you are looking for headings which are also links located in the "search" container.

Comment: Makes sense with good auto reporting system dev can be more relived

Answer (score 1):

Either will do what you are wanting but finding the a tag will be more stable and independent of any changes google will make.

I doubt google would change the .g but you never know. If you want the app to be as stable as possible the best way would be to look for the a tag that also contains an href. So any link on the page will get scraped no matter what google changes. From there you might have to do some additional filtering such as getting rid of any ads that might get picked up or anything off of googles headers and footers.